# Resque starts jobs, but do nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, resque

I'm using resque to do some (long time) job. And I have a few classes with the same mixed-in module for queuing. Class Service substitutes in tests, that's why it standalone and (maybe too much) complicated. So the story is when I call

```
Campaign.perform(user_id)
```

directly, everything works fine, but when I try to use queue:

```
Resque.enqueue(Campaign, user_id)
```

Job created, but seems like do nothing. At least, nothing saves into the database. Which is main task of Campaign class. I can see in resque-web-interface that jobs creates and finished, and finished (to fast, almost just after create) but no result.

I'm new in Resque and not really sure it calls it all (confused how to debug it).

Does anybody have similar problem? thanks for any help.

Module:

```
module Synchronisable
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def perform(user_id)
      save_objects("#{self.name}::Service".constantize.get_objects(user_id))
    end

    protected

    def save_objects(objects)
      raise ArgumentError "should be implemented"
    end
  end

  class Service
    def self.get_objects(user)
      raise ArgumentError "should be implemented"
    end
  end
end
```

One of the classes:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Synchronisable
  @queue = :app

  class << self
     protected 
       def save_objects(objects)
         #some stuff to save objects
       end

  end
  class Service
    def self.get_objects(user_id)
      #some stuff to get objects
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Jobs get enqueue but don't run most times. Once in a while it actually works.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question so not sure how rails folder structure was back then but I had the same problem and issue was with inheritance. Seems if you are using Resque your job classes shouldn't inherit from ApplicationJob.

so if your code was like this in (app/jobs/campaign_job.rb):

```
class Campaign < ApplicationJob
  @queue = :a_job_queue
  def self.perform
     #some background job
  end
end
```

then remove the inheritance i.e "< ApplicationJob"

Comment: April 2021 and I had the same problem: Rails 6 ActiveJob configured for Resque (following the Rails Guides examples) let Resque fail silently. No error messages, everything seemed normal, except the Jobs didn't get performed. So I switched the Job class syntax from Rails' ActiveJob example to the Resque syntax (regarding: the class inheritance, queue, perform) and everything worked. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, but I had the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

These jobs are almost certainly failing, due to an Exception.  What is resque-web showing you on the Failures tab?  You can also get this from the Rails console with:

```
Resque.info
```

or

```
Resque::Failure.all(0)
```

Comment: As I tell in the question, problem is my jobs looks not started at all. With no errors or exception (they not appears in Failures tab). But with doing nothing, too. I try to start them manually with command Resque.enqueue(Сampaign, user.id)

Comment: can you point us to an api-doc or something of that ilk? I'm really new to resque and need to investigate some failures.

Comment: @Ramy, just browse around in the code; there's not much of it in reality. You may be better just starting resque-web and browsing, as it shows in the README, however: https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/README.markdown

Answer (score 1):

You should run your worker like this:

```
nohup QUEUE=* rake resque:work & &> log/resque_worker_QUEUE.log
```

This will output everything you debug to "log/resque_worker_QUEUE.log" and you will be able to find out what's wrong with your Campaign class.

Comment: hm, after doing that I have resque_worker_QUEUE.log with only one blank line - still nothing happend when my job started/finished

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
env TERM_CHILD=1 COUNT=2 "QUEUE=*" bundle exec rake resque:workers
```